ATmega328PB Sleep Mode Current Consumption
I am using an ATmega328PB to run an RF module. When testing sleep mode current consumption, I noticed it was much higher than I expected. I took off all unnecessary components. The only things in the circuit are: ATmega328PB chip, a Pull-Up resistor between VCC and RESET pin, 10uF and 0.1uF capacitors between VCC and GND; the circuit boils down to the schematic below.

I'm running the chip at 8MHz internal and 3.3V. I have tried using the power_all_disable() function, setting all my pins up to be input pull-ups, setting the clock prescalar to clock_div_4, calling sleep_bod_disable() and I'm setting sleep mode to be Power Down mode. The datasheet(sec 33.3 page 352) says that the chip should use 3.2uA in this mode, but I'm measuring 110uA. Since my clock frequency is higher than the suggested 4MHz at 3.3V, I expect current consumption to be larger but not by this much. Here is all the code that I'm running.
void setup(){
    delay(2000) //just so i can compare current levels (4.8mA before sleep)
    power_all_disable();
    power_adc_disable();
    power_spi1_disable();
    power_spi_disable();
    power_timer0_disable();
    power_timer1_disable();
    power_timer2_disable();
    power_twi_disable();
    power_usart0_disable();
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 27; i++){
      pinMode(i, INPUT_PULLUP);
    }

    ADCSRA &= ~(1 << ADEN);
    ADCSRB &= ~(1 << ADEN);
    clock_prescale_set(clock_div_4);
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
    sleep_enable();
    sleep_bod_disable();
    sleep_mode();
 
    while(true);
}

loop(){

}

I'm measuring by hooking up a multimeter in series between my power source and my circuit. I know this may add a load to the circuit and therefore drive the current up, but the circuit I'm using as a reference is a different version of this module using an ATmega324P chip, which measures around 40uA in sleep mode through the same multimeter setup. If I could reduce my current consumption to about ~50uA through this setup it would be enough.
EDIT:
I compiled that same code above for an ATmega324PB and uploaded it onto the board I was using as a reference. It draws the same as the ATmega328PB (110uA). When I upload the old code that was present on it it drops down to 14uA. This very strongly suggests it is a software issue instead of hardware. Unfortunately the code is long and old, and not organized very well. Plus it's written in Atmel Studio which means I can't just move it all over to arduino, or move my arduino sketch to Atmel.
When trying to slowly deconstruct the code to figure out the difference, I found that commenting out a specific line:
//enable SPI, set as Master, set clock rate fck/8 = 500kHz
SPCR1 = (1 << SPE) | (1 << MSTR) | (1 << SPR0);

The device seemingly no longer sleeps. However in this case the current draw remains around 2.8mA and not the 110uA that my program produces.
Another thing I've noticed that I now believe could be the issue, is that while the chip is active (i.e. not asleep), my program has it running at 2.9mA vs the older code running it at 2.8mA. this 0.1mA difference is the same difference in sleep modes, which to me suggests that my code for some reason has something that is always on, where the older code does not / disables it, but I have no clue what.


Note that the ADEN bit belongs to ADCSRA, not to ADCSRB. 2. Could you try the recommended practice for sleeping with BOD disabled?


@EdgarBonet 1. I changed it to ACME although it made no difference.  2. The only difference is mine included an extra call to sleep_enable() after sleep_bod_disable()which shouldn't matter, but I did it anyway (no change in current)

This isn't the code you are running because it doesn't compile. There should be a semicolon on the sleep line, and void before loop.

Where did you purchase the ATMEGA328PB ? There are tales of "clone" ATMEGA328P devices which have higher than normal power consumption in sleep modes. These are sometimes fitted to boards such as the Pro Mini. Maybe there are also "clones" of the "PB" variant in circulation.

Running your code as a benchmark on my Atmega328P I got the following:
15 mA, then dropped to 141 µA.
However the following code:
#include <avr/sleep.h>
void setup() {
  delay(2000); //just so i can compare current levels (4.8mA before sleep)

  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
    pinMode (i, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(i, LOW);
  }
  
  // disable ADC
  ADCSRA = 0;

  set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
  noInterrupts ();           // timed sequence follows
  sleep_enable();
  // turn off brown-out enable in software
  MCUCR = bit (BODS) | bit (BODSE);
  MCUCR = bit (BODS); 
  interrupts ();
  sleep_cpu();

  while (true);
}

void loop() {

}

.. gave me 15.6 mA, then dropped to 0.128 µA (128 nA).

Turns out power_all_disable() and power_adc_disable() don't actually turn off the ADC, because as soon as I turned it off myself via register (I did ADCSRA &= ~(1<<ADEN); instead) the power dropped all the way down!
